# Getting 10 random items using Node & Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

I'm trying to work out how to best get a set of 10 random items from a Mongo collection. My plan is to store a set of Mongo IDs in Redis, use the Redis SRANDMEMBER command to get 10 random IDs and then obtain them from the Mongo collection.

Since I'm using Node, I'm unable to use SRANDMEMBER 10, as the node "redis" package doesn't accept the optional second parameter.

Where I'm really stumbling though is how to do this in an async-friendly way. I have tried using several of the tools provided by the node async library, such as Waterfall and While, but the Redis call always comes in later than the data.

---

Edit #2:

In response to help below, I've refined my function down the following:

```
client.send_command("SRANDMEMBER", ["album_id_set", "10"], function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.log('Redis error: ' + err);
    Album.find({
        '_id' : { $in: results }
    }, function(err, result){
        if (err) console.log('Mongo error: ' + err);
        response.json(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, using either the `redis` or `node-redis` package is to send the raw command.
I've tested both packages and both work for me.

### Using node-redis Package

https://github.com/tim-smart/node-redis

`node-redis` returns an array of buffer objects.

```
client.sendCommand('SRANDMEMBER', ['album_id_set', '10'], function(err, reply) {
    for (var i = 0; i < reply.length; i++) {
        console.log(reply[i].toString());
    };
});
```

### Using redis Package

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

`redis` returns an array of strings.

```
client.send_command('SRANDMEMBER', ['album_id_set', '10'], console.log);
```

See [send_command](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#clientsend_commandcommand_name-args-callback) documentation for more info.

Comment: This looks like the right idea. I've been unable to get it to work though, it's complaining about "wrong number of arguments for srandmember". Have you had more success?

Comment: @DonH just to confirm, are you using the `redis` module (that I linked to) or the `node-redis` module at https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-redis ? It works for me using the `redis` module.

Comment: Thanks for your help and edits myanimal, it's much appreciated. I'm using the "redis" module. I tried the example above but still the too many arguments error. I've put my code in as an edit in case that sheds any light?

Comment: @DonH, I suspect it may be the version of Redis server (`redis-server -v`) you are using. The second parameter to `SRANDMEMBER` was only only added recently. I used your code to test against version 2.6.7.

Comment: Good catch. I updated to 2.6.9 and it works well. I've adjusted my original question to include the code that solves the problem. Much more elegant than the waterfall below! Thanks.